# How to enable TLS version 1.2 in web logic for outgoing https transactions

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic12c, jsse, ibm-jdk

I am working on one project which require TLS version 1.2 to be enabled on web logic server for outgoing https transactions.
I tried using below properties in web logic startup script :
Weblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2
Or
Weblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS

But when I ran some test I was able to see TLSv1 still getting used in the clientHello message in weblogic SSL logs. We tried every permutation and combination to start the TLS handshake with TLSv1.2 but no success so far.

When we enabled sun based http handler in weblogic and used below property in startup script, I was able to use TLSv1.2
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

My question is how to enable TLSv1.2 in weblogic 12c version with IBM java 1.7 SR9 for outgoing https transactions when using weblogic http connection classes instead of sun based http classes?

Comment: Did you use a lower case `w` in `weblogic.security.SSL.*`?

Comment: Yes I did. All properties were configured properly

Answer (score 1):

You can enable TLSv1.2 for Outgoing connection from Weblogic.

Under the managed servfer, Server Startup in the arguments add as below

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

Answer (score 1):

pl update at server settings> Configuration > server start > Arguments

-DWeblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2 This helps.

Test with following commands.

```
    #openssl s_client  -connect localhost/ipaddress(remote):port(443) -tls1 

    #openssl s_client  -connect localhost/ipaddress(remote):port(443) -tls1_1 

    #openssl s_client  -connect localhost/ipaddress(remote):port(443) -tls1_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to -DUseSunHttpHandler=true with IBM JDK as well for Weblogic. Otherwise, it will pick the default http handler, weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.

You can find the details at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27046674.