# Compatible oracle version's for TLS 1.2

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need some help regarding the Oracle versions.

Actually we are planning to update the protocol TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2 in oracle servers. Want to know whether all the oracle version starting from 8i to 12C compatible with TLS 1.2 or not?
Your help will be really helpful and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked in Stackoverflow before
[TLS Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274507/how-to-enable-tls-version-1-2-in-web-logic-for-outgoing-https-transactions)

Below is the Oracle community thread regarding TLS support
[Oracle Community Thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3971622)